# Mac OS 内の Rails 環境下で Ruby のバージョンが正しく指定できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のような場合、どのような事が考えられるでしょうか…。
rails アプリのルートディレクトリでコマンドを叩いた結果です。

```
$ rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.2 (set by /Users/username/Documents/workspace/rails_root/.ruby-version)

$ rbenv versions --local
  system
* 2.2.2 (set by /Users/username/Documents/workspace/rails_root/.ruby-version)
```

zsh を使用していますが、`~/.zprofile` の内容はこのような感じです。

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

`which bundle` を実行すると
`/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/bundle` と返ってきます。

`bundle update` と `bundle install` は実行できます。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

既に確認済みでしたら申し訳ありません。
rbenvのruby 2.2.2にbundlerがインストールされていない可能性は無いでしょうか？

```
which bundle
```

を実行した結果が

```
/usr/bin/bundle
```

であれば、ruby 2.2.2のbundlerがインストールされていないので、

```
gem install bundler
```

でbundlerをインストールしてください。

Comment: 結果は

    $ which bundle
    /Users/username/.rbenv/shims/bundle

となります。